# Android application backup and restore?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, android-backup-service

For the application I'm creating, I'd like users to be able to backup their application data (to an SD card for instance). What I mean by application data is the preferences and SQLite database. I'd also like to make it possible to restore the data.

Is it possible to do this with BackupManager? If yes, can someone give me a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BackupManager is for saving your data to the cloud. To have something backed up to the SDcard, you could write some kind of a service for your application which does this. All the files/dbs/preferences can be written to a folder.

But, this approach also has a risk if the user formats his SD card or deliberately deletes the folder. You can have no control over that.